# How to fix number of dashes in matplotlib line graph? python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set a fixed number of dashes in line of graph

Suppose I have a value of 5 on 0-1(y-axis) then the line should have only 5 dashes from between 0 to 1 of Y values
my full code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

y_arr = [3,1,2,3,6,2]
x_arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# ax.axis("off")

ax.plot(x_arr, y_arr)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

This is what I want to do, [My expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDGo9.png)

**edited question to focus only one problem**

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your problem.

```
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

is doing exactly what it should. It is setting your minimal y to 0. Maybe you want to try

```
ax.set_xlim(left=0)
```

Or just set your limits in absolute values.

```
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
```

By default matplotlib is setting the axis automatically so that all values can be displayed.

Comment: okay, thank but that was not exactly I wanted to do.. I wanted to start the line from (0,0) coordinates then move to 3 value of Y... Although I fixed it by I had to compromise with the values of array like this  `y_arr.insert(0,0)`

Secondly, I can ignore this but my main concern is **setting the fix number of dashes** from point A to B

Comment: So I think I now understand what you want. I am not sure this is supported. Because each of your points have a different distance, 'dashed' would have to calculate the distance for each two points to then equally space the 5 dashed lines.